# SQL mixed String with leading zeros

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to get the maximum value of a table and then add that with +1.  The problem here is that the column contains leading zeros and the length of the column cannot be greater than 4.

Here an example:

Tablename: car

| id |
| --- |
| C001 |
| C002 |
| ... |
| C009 |

I have tried to solve this problem with this sql Query:

```
select concat(left(max(id),3),right(max(id),1)+1) as new from car;
```

result: C0010
The problem with this query is that if C009 is the largest entry, the query should return C010. With this query, however, it returns C0010.

Comment: Divide to numeric and char pats. Increase. Use LPAD for to add leading zeros. Concatenate char.

Comment: Make the `id` an int, auto increment. then add the `C` and pad to whatever length in the Presentation layer of your code. there is no need to do it in a column and cause yourself and the database extra work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(id, 1), LPAD(SUBSTRING(id FROM 2) + 1, 3, '0')) AS new
FROM car
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. I haven't understand one thing. What makes the ```id from 2``` statement ?

Comment: @KlausM. Extracts a substring from `id` value starting from 2nd char. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring